# jquery ui-tabs focus first text box in selected tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In previous versions I wrote following code to focus first text box of the selected tab:

```
$(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide) input[type='text']:first").focus();
```

This no longer works as `ui-tabs-hide` was removed as of version 1.9.x.

How can I target the first `input` of the active tab?

Here I put my full code.

```
$(function() {  
$("input:submit, button").button();  
$("#tabs").tabs({  
beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {  
       ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST';  
                    ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                        ui.panel.html(
                                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                                "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                    });
                }, beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
                   try {
                        frmGlbObject.validationEngine('hideAll');
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                },
                load: function(event, ui) {
                    var tabindex = $(ui.tab).index();
                    tableListIndex = tabindex;
                    frmGlbObject = $(".ui-tabs-active input[type='text']:first").closest("form");
                    $(".ui-tabs-active input[type='text']:first").focus();
                    frmGlbObject.validationEngine('attach');
                    divGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsdivs");
                    txtGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsajaxcall[type='text']")
                    hdnGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsajaxcall[type='hidden']")
                    $(".ui-tabs-panel").css('background-color', '#ddddff');

                    if (tabindex == 0) {
                        fun1();
                    } else if (tabindex == 1) {
                        fun2();
                    } else if (tabindex == 2) {
                        fun3();
                    }
                }, activate: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-tabs-active input[type='text']:first").focus();
                    frmGlbObject = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']:first").closest("form");
                    divGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsdivs");
                    txtGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsajaxcall[type='text']")
                    hdnGlbObject = $(frmGlbObject).find(".clsajaxcall[type='hidden']")
                    $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']").bind("keydown", function(e) {
                        var n = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']").length;
                        if (e.which == 13) {
                            e.preventDefault(); //Skip default behavior of the enter key
                            var nextIndex = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']").index(this) + 1;
                            if (nextIndex < n)
                                $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']")[nextIndex].focus();
                            else {
                                //$(':input:not(input[type=hidden])')[nextIndex-1].blur();
                                //$('.clsbtnsubmit').click();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });
```

Here I have two problem :

1. frmGlbObject = $(".ui-tabs-panel:not(.hide) input[type='text']:first").closest("form");
2. $(".ui-tabs-active input[type='text']:first").focus();

The above statement is not working in Jquery Latest version .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not target `ui-state-active` or `ui-tabs-active` instead?

```
$('.ui-state-active input[type="text"]:first').focus();
```

That'll focus the first `input[type="text"]` of the active tab.

Or bind a listener to the `tabsactivate` event:

```
$('.selector').on('tabsactivate', function( event, ui ) {
    // focus input
});
```

#### [See Tabs API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)

Comment: First Thanks for your reply, I have changed my code but it does not work.I put my full code here

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#tabContainer").tabs("option", "active", 1);
          $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtboxID').focus();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!